# Throw an object in swipe direction with angle and force in BOX2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I want to throw an object on touches ended method with force and left to right direction.I created world and body object and calculated swipe distance, angle and force but it is not working properly. Here is my code- --

```
- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"tocuehs began");

    UITouch *touch=[touches anyObject];
    point1 = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
}

- (void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch=[touches anyObject];
    point2 = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];

    float distance = ccpDistance(point1, point2);
    int maxDistance = 50;
    CGFloat strength = distance / maxDistance;
    CGFloat angle = atan2f(point2.y - point1.y, point2.x - point1.x);
    angle = - 1 * CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angle);
    //  int force = strength * maxForce;
    _body->ApplyLinearImpulse(b2Vec2(10.0f+cos(angle)*25.0f,10.0f+sin(angle)*25.0f), _body->GetPosition());
}
```

Please help!

Comment: Can you explain, what mean "not working properly"? How it works? By the way, try GetWorldCenter() instead of GetPosition().

Comment: I tried with GetWorldCenter() also.I want to throw a body by finger swipe not by dragging that body.like this game https://itunes.apple.com/tr/app/caveman-crush-love-machine/id662829479?mt=8

Comment: Hey i am looking for the same, did you get the solution?

Comment: Please reply me with the solution i have same requirement, i am stuck in it.